# Is it possible to insert an arithmetic operation in an insert sql statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've got a simple question, although it might be a bit difficult to explain.

I have a table and this table has three column with the following values already populated : Account Balance, Charge, Amount Paid in

```
Initially Account balance = £00.00
Charge = £200.00
Amount Paid in = £100
```

The value of the `Account balance`, is dependent on the following arithmetic operation: `Charge - Amount Paid in` which is `200 - 100 = 100`.

How would I represent that in an SQL statement? So what I mean is, how would I be able to populate the value in the Account column using an SQL statement which contain the arithmetic operation `Charge - Amount paid in`?

Apologies for the long post. I'm very new to SQL and so I'm just trying to get my head around it.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that sample data and desired results would be helpful.  I don't have a good idea of what the table looks like and what you want to do . . . an `insert` or `update`.

Comment: please describe your table here to get better answers

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you don't need to do this at all and you don't need an account balance column. You only need to save the amount paid and the charge. You can calculate the account balance at any time using

```
SELECT (sum(charge) - sum(paid)) as account balance FROM my_table where ...
```

Note that in your present attempt you are not taking into consideration the brought forward balance where as a query of the above nature does.

Comment: +1 Thanks! But where would this value be stored? So what i need to do is populate the a value in this account balance column based on the calculation (charge - amount paid) the reason is because i want to later pull out this value and display in a field on this app that i am creating. Apologies if I've rambled a bit here.

Comment: Like I said, there is no need to store it and usually in RDBMS we don't store something if it's the result of a simple calculation. The query I have given you is how you retrieve it. Of course how you display it depends on what your application does .

Comment: you may use triggers - INSERT AFTER trigger and update your table row with calculation @e4c5 has mentioned

Comment: Indeed @JavaHopper a trigger maybe used but that is to make things even more complicated. Good software is about keeping things as simple as possible.

Comment: Correct! for that matter, the values that are computed need not be stored in DB at all, unless it is the result of some complex operation which is time consuming and frequently retrieved

Comment: @JavaHopper exactly what I am trying to convince Mahbs to do! Thank you for your input

Comment: @JavaHopper is INSERT AFTER an sql keyword? Because when i googled it, i found that its something used in JQuery, just wondering how i would use that in conjunction with SQL. Apologies if it sounds like a stupid question.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

You may search for "INSERT AFTER trigger"

Comment: @JavaHopper Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. +1 or Thank you is better said by upvoting/rising the flag here at StackOverflow :-)